# How can I fix this error so I may proceed making a register and login system for my website?

Tags: php, mysql

I know that php is getting very old but it is the only coding that i partially know that is easy enough to use for a registration and login system. If more coding or information is needed then please ask before marking as a non-question.

I keep receiving the error below. My init.php and config.php are included. mysql info has been changed for the protection of my website.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')' in /home/a5236314/public_html/ooplr/core/init.php on line 20

init.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$GLOBALS['config'] = array(
'mysql' => array(
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'db' => 'lr'
),
'remember' => array(
    'cookie_name' => 'hash',
    'cookie_expiry' => 604800
),
'session' => array(
    'session_name' => 'user'
)
);

spl_autoload_register(function($class){  // 'This is line 20'
require_once 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
});

require_once 'functions/sanitize.php';
```

config.php

```
<?php
class Config{
public static function get($path = null) {
    if($path) {
        $config = $GLOBALS['config'];
        $path = explode('/', $path);

        print_r($path);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Anonymous functions in `spl_autoload_register` are only allowed in PHP 5.3.0, is your php version greater?

Comment: The entire first part of the question, including the title, is superfluous fluff. Please concentrate on the problem at hand. Thank you.

Comment: which php version are you running? 5.2? It seems that you closure-autoload function is not recognized, so you just need to use a named function. By the way if you're running 5.2 you should be warned that this is and [EOL php version](http://php.net/eol.php), so no more security updates!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP versions older than 5.3, anonymous functions are seen as syntax errors. To pass a callback function, do this:

```
function callback($class){  
    require_once 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
}
spl_autoload_register('callback');
```

Comment: omg thank you. adding this part of code has fixed it. thank you for your assistance!